# Improve Regex to match duplicates in a list

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regex to find dupliates in a list. It is only a short comma seperated list, and performance is not an issue, so there is no need to tell me I should not use regex for those reasons.

```
// returns a match because some is repeated
"some,thing,here,some,whatever".match(/(^|,)(.+?)(,|,.+,)\2(,|$)/g)
```

### Questions...

1. Can this regex be improved?
2. Does it cover all possible scenarios where comma is not in the seperated strings
3. Is there a better (preferably more readable and more efficient) way to do this?

Comment: Maybe just use non-capturing groups where you don't need to capture anything: `/(?:^|,)(.+?)(?:,|,.+,)\1(?:,|$)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the purpose of using regexes here, unless you like unimaginable pain. If I had to find duplicates I would

- Obtain an array of words

  ```
  var words = "...".split(',');
  ```
- optionally lowercase everything, if you feel like doing that
- sort the array

  ```
  words.sort()
  ```
- Duplicates should now all be in consecutive positions of the array.

As an extra advantage, I`m pretty sure this would be vastly more efficient than a regex version.

Comment: interesting - you could use a very simple regex to find duplicates that are next to each other... so `"string,of,things".split(',').sort().join(',').match(/(^|,).+?,\1(,|$)/)`

Comment: Also, I am not sure that it would be more efficient than regex which I think has an undeserved reputation for performance. It actually performs quite well, because it cuts off as soon as it finds a path that can not return a match. I would like to see a benchmark test of both methods... in fact I think I might do it.

Comment: ok, your method is about 10 times faster - as you can see from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ss4z/

Comment: how do you propose to find the duplicates? By looping through the array and doing comparison with element behind?

Comment: Thats the basic idea - the hashtable method from jfriend should be simpler though. As for efficiency, our methods splitting the array are around O(N) or O(NlogN) while complex regexes with backreferences often take exponential time!

Comment: according to my simple benchmark - your method is the fastest: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ss4z/1/

Comment: Your benchmark only stores the duplicates in the object version (in the other one you just mark a boolean) this could be warping the results.

Comment: please improve the benchmark as you see fit, and updaye the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to find dups in a comma separated list, I'd do it like this, using the hash capabilities of an object to accumulate unique values and detect dups:

```
function getDups(list) {
    var data = list.split(",");
    var uniques = {}, dups = {}, item, uniqueList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        item = data[i];
        if (uniques[item]) {
            // found dup
            dups[item] = true;
        } else {
            // found unique item
            uniques[item] = true;
        }
    }
    // at the end here, you'd have an object called uniques with all the unique items in it
    // you could turn that back into an array easily if you wanted to
    // Since it uses the object hash for dup detection, it scales to large numbers of items just fine
    // you can return whatever you want here (a new list, a list of dups, etc...)
    // in this implementation, I chose to return an array of unique values
    for (var key in uniques) {
        uniqueList.push(key);
    }
    return(uniqueList);    // return array of unique values
}

var list = "some,thing,here,some,whatever";
getDups(list);
```

Here's a jsFiddle that shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/NGQCz/

This type of implementation scales well with large numbers of words because the dup detection is relatively efficient.